# How change shape of Tabs to looks like Google Chrome

Tags: c++, qtstylesheets, border-image

How can I change the shape of my tabs inside my QTabWidget to looks like google chrome using border-image ?

Comment: How did the border image method fail? Did it crash? Did it show the wrong image?

Comment: Nope, she did nothing, I don't understand how to use it, I need to use a working image ?

Comment: Ok I solved this, I had to set no background color and use a picture with transparence.

Comment: Write an answer and accept it so that future generations don't have to go through that. Also try to edit your answer so that people with the same problem find your question via some search engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. First I had to remove all style applyed to the tabs like background-color.
Next I made a pciture with the wanted shape by and putting transparence where needed.